# How to show profile picture along with mail id in using Account Picker API in android

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin, accountpicker

I am working on making a user login with with google plus in my android app. So on click of the button an account picker is shown to him which just contains a list of mail ids registered on device and an option to add new account.(This is done using account picker api of android) Now I also want to display the profile picture of the registered ids along with their mail id.

[this is how i want it to appear with account picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Ay2.png)

[This is how it currently shows by using google login Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op5OV.png)

Why i cant use google login api directly because it takes a long time before the list can be shown leaving with no feedback to user for clicking on google login.
Thanks in advance